# codeigniter checkbox implode function error

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

Here is my View

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <select name="speciality"  class="form-control" required >
        <option value="" selected="selected" >Liste speciality</option>
        <option value="ag" >spec1</option>
        <option value="al" >spec2</option>
        <option value="pvc">spec3</option>
        <option value="MEDC">spec4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="parquet" name="products[]">
        product1
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="fplancher" name="products[]">
        product2
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="fauxplafonddem" name="products[]">
        product3
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="cloison" name="products[]">
        product4 
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="cloisonamovible" name="products[]"> 
        product5 
    </label>

    <div class="bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAdd" value="1"  type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-mail-reply-all"> &nbsp;save</i> </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" > <i class="fa fa-ban">&nbsp;cancel</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my Controller

```
public function add() {
         $prod=implode(',',$this->input->post('products'));
           $data=array('nomsoc'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                    'specialitesoc'=>$this->input->post('speciality'),
                    'produitssoc'=>$prod);
           if ($this->input->post("btnAdd", false))
            { 
            if($this->SocieteModel->add($data))
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 
                '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Société ajoutée avec succès </div>');
                redirect("/societe/");
            } 

       }
    $this->layout->title(' campany Title'); // Set page title
                $this->LoadViewBlocks("societe","","",true,true,true);
                $data["bodyId"]="register-bg";
                $this->layout->view('backend/societe/add', $data);
        }
```

When I load the View to add new campany, I got the error :

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning Message:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed
Line Number: 41

Any body can help please!

Comment: What happens if you use double qoutes?                        $prod=implode(",",$this->input->post('products'));

Comment: same problem with double quotes

Comment: You are using same method to load add view and save add view?

Comment: print_r($this->input->post('products')); and see if its an array before using implode

Comment: Poria where to place print_r($this->input->post('products')); ?

Comment: Paresh Gami, I think no problem with the function name, because in the save it used in the model

Comment: Place it before the implode or in the view maybe add an exit; after the print_r

Comment: I try the print_r($this->input->post('products')); in the view and in the controller no thing happens

Comment: I try also var_dump($prod) then it return NULL

Answer (score 0):

1. A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed Line Number: 41

Above error will come if `$this->input->post('products')` value is empty or not an array. Make sure you have array values for that.

2. I have tried your code. It was working fine only. Please go through on it.

   I used this view page.

   ```
   <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/forms/add" method="post"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
     <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select name="speciality"  class="form-control" required >
                <option value="" selected="selected" >Liste speciality</option>
                <option value="ag" >spec1</option>
                <option value="al" >spec2</option>
                <option value="pvc">spec3</option>
                <option value="MEDC">spec4</option>                     
        </select>
     </div>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox"  value="parquet" name="products[]">
             product1</label>
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox"  value="fplancher" name="products[]">    product2</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="fauxplafonddem" name="products[]">
                   product3</label>
                   </div>
                   <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox"  value="cloison" name="products[]">
                                  product4 </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                     <input type="checkbox"  value="cloisonamovible" name="products[]"> product5 </label>
        <div class="bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAdd" value="1"  type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-mail-reply-all"> &nbsp;save</i> </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" > <i class="fa fa-ban">&nbsp;cancel</i></button>
                   </div>

                   </form>
   ```

And in mycontroller

```
public function add() {
         $prod=implode(',',$this->input->post('products'));
           $data=array('nomsoc'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                    'specialitesoc'=>$this->input->post('speciality'),
                    'produitssoc'=>$prod);
           print_r($data); exit();
           if ($this->input->post("btnAdd", false))
            { 
            if($this->SocieteModel->add($data))
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 
                '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Société ajoutée avec succès </div>');
                redirect("/societe/");
            } 

       }
                $this->layout->title(' campany Title'); // Set page title
                $this->LoadViewBlocks("societe","","",true,true,true);
                $data["bodyId"]="register-bg";
                $this->layout->view('backend/societe/add', $data);
    }
```

While i used print_r($data); It worked correctly for me.

Comment: While I used print_r($data) it display Array ( [nomsoc] => [specialitesoc] => [produitssoc] => [activitessoc] => [dirigeantsoc] => [telsoc] => [faxsoc] => [ville] => [adressesoc] => [facebooksoc] => [twittersoc] => [gplussoc] => [linkedinsoc] => [youtubesoc] => [emailsoc] => )

Comment: Did you change anything in your view file.

Comment: input type="checkbox"  value="cloisonamovible" name="products[]"> product5 </label> Put open tag.

Comment: the <form ... action ... method ...> exist in my view and I change no thing

Comment: Did you put open tag in prodcuts checkbox.

Comment: the tag is opened and closed correctly , any other tag to open Sir Kaja

Comment: please which tag is not opened ?

Comment: That only. Other than that everything fine.

Comment: Any body please know about the issue

Comment: I found the solution , Thank you every body who gives help

Comment: What is the problem? Let me know.

Comment: the solution is to make $prod=implode(',',(Array) $this->input->post('products'));

Comment: (array) before $this->input->post(products)

Comment: basically $this->input->post('products') it will return array data only know. then why again array.

Comment: I think because it returns an empty object not an array, so we've to parse that object into an array

Comment: never. You are using name="products[]" as array name only. So it will return array. I think when you are not selecting any product. That time only you got error.